# Access notes created in PDF on Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8

In Windows 8 I can open up any PDF file in the native new PDF viewer and add notes by highlighting text and clicking "Add a Note".

I would love to be able to programmatically access these notes using C#. But I am having trouble finding them. I can easily enough enumerate through document properties but I cannot find the notes at all...

Here is my code:

```
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".pdf");
        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        var props = await file.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(new List<string> { });

        foreach (var key in props.Keys)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("key: " + key + " value: " + props[key]);
        }

        var docProp = await file.Properties.GetDocumentPropertiesAsync();
        var allDocProperties = await docProp.RetrievePropertiesAsync(new List<string> { });

        foreach (var key in allDocProperties.Keys)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("key: " + key + " value: " + allDocProperties[key]);
        }
```

But none of the properties I am seeing in the output window have anything to do with the notes I have created in the PDF.

Can anyone else help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of this was that I had to port over just enough of the code from iTextView into .NETCore, which was a big pain but I got enough of it working so that I can pass in a `byte[]` and extract the annotations.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Reader also stores them inside of its own isolated storage. Specifically, the notes are located in the LocalState\PLM\Document folder in Microsoft Reader's isolated storage. You can find each app's isolated storage in AppData\Local\Packages in the user profile.

Comment: Are you sure? When I add the note the file size does increase and when I open the PDF with Acrobat Reader I can also see the note which would suggest that its written into the file itself.

Comment: When I tested it just now, it didn't increase for me nor can I see the notes in Adobe Reader. Maybe it only works for certain types of PDFs - which wouldn't be a surprise since this is beta software. But since you're seeing that, I'll edit my post.